# What does DATABASE_URL mean in Heroku pgbackups?

Tags: heroku

The following list is generated when I typed "heroku pgbackups". At some point I started a new Maroon database and deleted the Gold database. My primary database is now Maroon. I started using auto backup sometime when the ID starts going to a00x. I am confused as to the difference between DATABASE and DATABASE_URL as I think my auto backups are backing up the wrong database since the size of the database decreased. b023 is a backup I just generated and the name of the database is again different. Can someone help me understand the naming conventions here? Thank you. Be gentle, I'm a newbie here.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

from: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups

Creating a backup

Backups are compressed. The size of a backup will be less than the size of your database.
By default, PG Backups operates against your primary database (located at the DATABASE_URL config var location).

```
$ heroku pgbackups:capture

HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BLACK (DATABASE_URL)  ----backup--->  b251

Capturing... done
Storing... done
```

If you have multiple databases on your application, you can choose which one to backup by specifying the database name:

```
$ heroku pgbackups:capture HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_PINK

HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_PINK  ----backup--->  b252

Capturing... done
Storing... done
```